# strcpy, assignment from strtok to a variable length struct string

Tags: c, string

```c
typedef struct {
    long f1; 
    char f2[FIELD2_STRING_LENGTH];
    char* f3; 
} bankRecord;



while (fgets(line, 1000, file)) {
        record *rptr = malloc(sizeof(record));
        char *token = strtok(line, ",");
        rptr->f1 = atol(token); // works fine
        strcpy(rptr->f2,strtok(NULL, ",")) // works fine
        rptr->f3 = strtok(NULL, ","); // fails, at the end, all records have the same data in f3, if strcpy is used - causes segmentation fault
        records[i++] = record; 
    }
```

The code is extracted from a csv file reader method. The csv file has the format `"long integer, fixed Character string, variable Character String"`.
`records` is an array of pointers to record objects (type `record **`). At the end of the while loop all the records seem to have the same value of f3 (the last one added) while correct values are stored for f1 and f2. I can't figure out what's causing this because both f2 and f3 are strings. Changing f3's assignment to strcpy from "=" causes segmentation fault.

Comment: Suppose you have a file of 1000 lines. Each line has two string fields. The first string field has FIELD2_STRING_LENGTH characters and the second one has 500 characters. How many bytes does your program need to store all the text fields? How many bytes does your program allocate? Where does the difference go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
br->f3 = strtok(NULL, ",");
```

sets a pointer to the internals of strtok. It doesnt copy the string. Basically all your f3 pointers point at the same location.

You need

```
br->f3 = strdup(strtok(NULL, ","));
```

to make a copy of the string at that point. You will need to free the memory later

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242317/discussion-on-answer-by-pm100-strcpy-assignment-from-strtok-to-a-variable-lengt).